# Shopify returns "token unauthorised" in CakePHP app

Tags: shopify

I am working for a public app all thing working fine. Issue came when I uninstall the app and re-install the Shopify app then api call seems not working.

When I go through what the issue with Api then it gives error token unauthorized; this is same token that I got when I install the app first time but after re-install the app that token seems not working.

How can I get token when I am re-installing the app and what would be condition n? I am  using CakePHP library for Shopify app.

I thought might be issue with session and cookie so I register the app/uninstall web hook and removed session cookie but some time web hook not called immediately.

Answer (score 0):

***About Token***

I feel like you need to update your token when user install your application every time.

while re-installing it may possible that shopify return same token as early install.

I personally store token to database not to session.
so try that out also.

***About webhook***

And You can trust uninstall webhook in shopify i used in 45+ applications and it is work super fine for me.

***About Error***

Post your following code 
 1. app installation code where you are retrieving token and saving it to database/session.
 2. uninstall webhook where you are removing token from database/session.